# Get the best feature which gives the largest information gain

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am given this dataset:

```
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data
```

I have to get the best feature based on the fact that it has the largest information gain. I was doing it manually. But is there a way that I could get it calculated using sklearn or any other library?

Just for the reference I was writing this code:

```
false_count=0.0;
true_count=0.0;
total=0.0;
for x in range(0, len(y_train)):
    if y_train[x]==2:

              false_count=false_count+1;
              total=total+1;

    else: 

             true_count=true_count+1
             total=total+1

Entropy = -(true_count/total)*(math.log((true_count/total))/math.log(2))-(false_count/total)*(math.log((false_count/total))/math.log(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) in the Scikit-Learn docs which explains all the resources available in the library for feature selection.

I understand by your dataset that you have a classification problem. That means that [the chi square stat](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2) may be useful for feature selection.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to calculate entropy loss, sklearn has a function `metrics.log_loss`, [official documents](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiu5uH6xdnWAhXJHpQKHaigB_kQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fscikit-learn.org%2Fstable%2Fmodules%2Fgenerated%2Fsklearn.metrics.log_loss.html&usg=AOvVaw0YGMkuGa8lby2ZX8vJvHYj):
    usage eg:

```
log_loss(Y_Truth, Y_predicted, normalize=True)
```